# Appium : application restarting continuously in real IPAD

Tags: ios, appium

My application is restarting continuously while running the script through Eclipse.
Script :

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    cap.setCapability("device", "iPAD");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "xxx's Ipad");
    cap.setCapability("version", "8.1.2");
    File app = new   File("/Users/xxx/Documents/Softwares/UICatalog.app");
    cap.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), cap);
    driver.quit();
```

I have also have set the app path in the appium server. I have also checked while giving the app path in the script only and then in the appium server only.
I copied the app from the location :
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UICatalog-aibgscbrnzcxdfecyxuswfxkbnnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UICatalog.app

Earlier I had used this location directly in the script and in the appium server but with no effect. 
I mentioned the BundleId in the appium server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the timeout for your Test Cases sometimes app may get restarted if we set very small timeout so make sure you given enough time to run your test cases.

Also if your File path capability not working another alternative is to provide the First activity to start with like:

```
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "LG Nexus 5");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.packageName");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","ui.activity.SplashActivity");
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I think the appPackage and appActivity is required for the android devices. However I have solved the problem . Need to turn on the UI Automation in the device. You will find the option in Settings —> Developer —>Enable UI Automation.